# problema con funciones de c++

Tags: c++, funciones, bucles

Este código es para ingresar un numero tomándolo como si fueran dolares y después dar cambio de 100, 50, 20, 10, 5 y 1 dolares pero dando la menor cantidad de cada uno.

El problema es que no da el cambio, aquí les dejo el código:

[Ejecutar código completo en Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAJlICsupVs1qhkAUm4AhSVNIBnTO2QE8dSplroAwqlYBXALa0Q3AGylN6ADJ5amAHJGARpmJdeAB1TzCa2roGxqYW3r6qdLb2Toau7jwKSpgq/gwEzMQEgUYm5onKEbRpGQRRji5uHgrpmdnBefI1pXblsZU8AJQKqPrEyBwA5JIAzHbIBlgA1OLD2mqNxJjMhjPY4gAMAIIbm/q%2BopO0y5jynsz9k43oMzJbOwBuqHjokyyxahB2BJPoehknpEmX2m5mQeE0gOBkjMYNoyH0mnSkPoILM90wX0wyO%2B0PwmAAXtjUbC0ETofpaKgOtMAOy3TaTRmTADuCDw7Agv2Ei3kMwAIvz1tTxHSdkzxUCqJy/jzVvzOOshSL6RLVa9wbRZPKbmK1eKuf95ABaeWKnVbPUigUWtVKRSS6Xck5y4Z8gCsStFNr1jJJCPozC1rs45oZPsZBp5JtdHtDlpp1rDqrtmAdkedwzWru4npV4cm6MxQb5IeGefD6eN/JzcbVVt1ydY9rwUsrLpLuYbPrx%2BOLpfL3ZlJ2jHdrqvr3olKbTQ95mf5bo6yq7epJqD7Y8HTqrMc34onSanTdTLcdhvbnCXXsPeop6%2Bk2rLK7VlZH/efjIP%2B4TOwPDyeLzyGwzzMJ8KLQmCEJAuBoJjP6SLQTi5iFvQWKIaiPZkrBcKoFhZh3sK17img%2BgEDM2jkVYrDkTR3DcOIbraAQbzOGokj0bMlFaNRT6TiRZGcZxdGQbQPyziAIIcRRswiTRsxUZu/FyRRwlwYizBiduEnscpfrqcpCm8YeSmCSp3AoQQqaVtpdHKRZmAGdxik9AJ0lmT2mmGjZUnkT2jnoDxA4mW57Frp5PLebpYzrqZhlBS5ynsRS4WRaZd7%2BYFv4/ncWzAoYzB2BAhEDsCsmuusgJ6QGgqAvZNU/OCvblZV0X1el5WbsCbZGfufEJaZ7FfMQGD6GCxCTEokyGHQRA/FZ4mSYpdgurgs6hl2LEfJWLVQVVCH2YCmHqjhgIEZuQGsCBEAiS1cLwcwtUYqhh2NbdpKTGdPVMl2iwEL0onrOtCYDF0rAgAMboDKQJgDOsUOoODKkyNIlw9H0qYjJwUMEODcMdF0ADWIBupwAB03A0usZiU5wAAsNIAJxuvTbpCODtNQzDcOkAjAxQ/IIAVTjsMg6QcCwEgmAAB7JKRJDkJQGTAPIAAKIhKAwCCoMyMNY6QaCGJ47LMIUav2Kwmva1zUMG0b7DuMACq8Lb7JuAA8qRls67jUPS8kmzEMr4O%2BzLyBpPguselDND0EwbAcHT/CCMIogoFq0hCHgzgC5AXSoJ4hQC3z3S9P0ghXHYZsa1r3si6D4OQ9DPs8%2BDUsABxmEaZi05MwDIMgkwKuTkzYKHcvjRAuCECQILDJekxI7I2M%2B/jpBE7TbekzS3AM8MO9t26Oa04fzNswMHNNyLLfFwLQsr/XAzcJzze88vdddOixC%2BOotNAA%3D%3D)

Esta es la parte inicial, es lo que esta dentro del `int main()`.

```cpp
int main() {
    int cien=0, cincuenta=0, veinte=0, diez=0, cinco=0, uno=0;
    int dolares;
    
    cout<<"introducir el monto de dolares: ";
    cin>>dolares;
    
    cambio(dolares, cien, cincuenta, veinte, diez, cinco, uno);
    salida(cien, cincuenta, veinte, diez, cinco, uno);
    
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Esto es parte de una función encargada de dar el cambio.

```cpp
void cambio(int dolares, int &cien, int &cincuenta, int &veinte, int &diez, int &cinco, int &uno) {
    while(dolares==0){
        if(dolares>=100){
            cien+=1;
            dolares-=100;
        }
        else if(dolares>=50){
            cincuenta+=1;
            dolares-=50;
        }
        else if(dolares>=20){
            veinte+=1;
            dolares-=20;
        }
        else if(dolares>=10){
            diez+=1;
            dolares-=10;
        }
        else if(dolares>=5){
            cinco+=1;
            dolares-=5;
        }
        else if(dolares>=1){
            uno+=1;
            dolares-=1;
        }
    }
}
```

Esto es parte de una función encargada de imprimir los resultados de la anterior funcion.

```cpp
void salida(int &cien, int &cincuenta, int &veinte, int &diez, int &cinco, int &uno) {
    cout<<endl<<"\tcambio"<<endl;
    cout<<"cien dolares: "<<cien<<endl;
    cout<<"cincuenta dolares: "<<cincuenta<<endl;
    cout<<"veinte dolares: "<<veinte<<endl;
    cout<<"diez dolares: "<<diez<<endl;
    cout<<"cinco dolares: "<<cinco<<endl;
    cout<<"un dolar: "<<uno<<endl;
}
```

Si se preguntan el código corre normal, no me sale ningún error al tratar de abrirlo, el problema esta  en que no me da el resultado que debería de dar.
aquí les pongo el desarrollo del problema

```
introducir el monto de dolares: 150
    cambio
cien dolares: 0
cincuenta dolares: 0
veinte dolares: 0
diez dolares: 0
cinco dolares: 0
un dolar: 0
```

Se espera que la salida sea

```
introducir el monto de dolares: 150
    cambio
cien dolares: 1
cincuenta dolares: 1
veinte dolares: 0
diez dolares: 0
cinco dolares: 0
un dolar: 0
```

Comment: @trauma creo que a esto es a lo que te refieres no???

Comment: las partes del código están arriba para que lo copien y peguen

Comment: Se espera que coloques un código que este listo para copiar y pegar, y que al menos simule tu problema. Aunque, con la información que proporcionas, es suficiente para replicarlo, es necesario cumplir con esto, porque no es bien recibido responder preguntas mal formateadas.

Comment: perdón si no lo estoy haciendo bien, para la próxima me informare de como hacer bien las preguntas

Comment: entenderé si no quieren responder

Comment: Acabo de enviar una posible edición. Espero que pueda servirte como ejemplo del código de formato del sitio.

Comment: @edwin ¿Por qué en vez de usar tantos `else if`, no usas un switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El siguiente código muestra el problema. El ciclo while solo se ejecuta cuando `dolares == 0`, es decir, cuando no se requiere hacer el cambio.

```cpp
void cambio(int dolares, int &cien, int &cincuenta, int &veinte, int &diez, int &cinco, int &uno) {
    while(dolares!=0) { // <--- El problema estaba aquí, tenias `dolares == 0`
        if(dolares>=100){
            cien+=1;
            dolares-=100;
        }
        else if(dolares>=50){
            cincuenta+=1;
            dolares-=50;
        }
        else if(dolares>=20){
            veinte+=1;
            dolares-=20;
        }
        else if(dolares>=10){
            diez+=1;
            dolares-=10;
        }
        else if(dolares>=5){
            cinco+=1;
            dolares-=5;
        }
        else if(dolares>=1){
            uno+=1;
            dolares-=1;
        }
    }
}
```

```
introducir el monto de dolares: 124
    cambio
cien dolares: 1
cincuenta dolares: 0
veinte dolares: 1
diez dolares: 0
cinco dolares: 0
un dolar: 4
```

[Probar este código](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAJlICsupVs1qhkAUm4AhSVNIBnTO2QE8dSplroAwqlYBXALa1Bm9ABk8tTADkjAI0zEQAFgDMpAA6p5hNbV0DY0FvX1U6S2s7Q0dndwUlTBV/BgJmYgJAoxNOBOVw2lT0gkjbBydXD3k0jKzg3Ori0ujYyoBKBVR9YmQOAHJJNytkAywAanE3bTVq4kxmQ0nscQAGAEFVtf1fUTHaBcx5T2Zeser0SZl1zYA3VDx0MZYYtQgrAjH0PXTD0jH3ibcABsyDwmj%2BAMkIOG%2Bk0aQh9EBQJumHemARHyh%2BEwAC8MUjQbQ0PiofpaKg2hMAOxXNZjeljADuCDw7AgX2Ec3kYDAkwAIitKeIaZsGWL/lR2d8uUt%2BZwVoLhbTxSqnmDaLI5ZdRaqxRyfvIALRyhXa9a64V8nUqpSKCVSzmHWVuPkAVkVIvNuoZhOQsPozE1Ls4Zrp3vp%2Bq5xpd7tDFqpVq9NtYdrwksjTrcyxd3A9yvDYxRaKDfJDbnz4YzRv5ubjqst1vFtsw9qrztLecbuuxOJLZYr3qr0Y7dZVDaTTZTLbTDoN7ddbSVXdVvtQfdHg%2Blh2Hro3YvHYeTqfTW/k7c4i89h%2B9ZLX0i15eXKqHD4H%2B4TjYPX/WdweZzYDzMG8iJQqC4L/CBwK%2Bv68IQZiwJFvQ6JwUiPYklBwyoOhQK3kKV5img%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%2BA69wHOkDQ9BMGwHB0/wgjCKIKCatIQh4PYGmQB0qCeAUGl8503S9II5xWKb6ua17wtgxDUMw97PMQ5LAAcQKGkCLhjMAyDIGM8oU2M2Ah7LI0QLghAkICbgXmMyOyDj3sE6QxMuG3ZNUtwDNuDvbeurmLiH8zbN9FHVst8XAukEL%2BP1303Cc83vPL3XHQosQvjqC4QA%3D%3D)

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, no me di cuenta de ese pequeño detalle

Answer (score 1):

Tal y como te ha indicado [ristobal Montecino](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/376337/2742), el problema radica en que no entras en el bucle principal de tu función ya que nunca le pasas a la función un valor cero.

Mi aporte a esta respuesta se va a centrar en la mejora de tu algoritmo, que es difícil de mantener y muy poco flexible; es mucho más sencillo hacer un bucle para estos cálculos:

```
int valores[] { 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1 };
int cantidad[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

int valor;
std::cin >> valor;

for (int indice = 0; indice != 6; ++indice)
{
    cantidad[indice] = valor / valores[indice];
    valor %= valores[indice];
}
```

El código anterior guarda en `cantidad` cuántas unidades de cambio de cada tipo hay que devolver, es mucho más fácil de mantener que tu versión ya que si quieres añadir otras unidades de cambio sólo hay que añadir un número a la formación de `valores`, pero se puede hacer aún más flexible usando una función plantilla variádica:

```
template <int ... VALORES>
auto cambio(int valor)
{
    int valores[] { VALORES ... };
    std::array<int, sizeof...(VALORES)> cantidad {};

    for (int indice = 0; indice != sizeof...(VALORES); ++indice)
    {
        cantidad[indice] = valor / valores[indice];
        valor %= valores[indice];
    }

    return cantidad;
}
```

El código anterior [puede usarse así](https://tio.run/##bVHLasMwEDxbX7F1KTjYSZNACMQP6CG3QqGFXtIcVFkJAlsythxoQn@97sryI4EchLUzO6PZNSuKKcuoPDbNo5Asq1MOkVCVLjnNEzJiui4yfg3QsqQ/CSGa50VGtZFJDbPZDD5fXt/etx8JobVWwGj@LZRnyBPNVDkhF@IMFa92e7j0klb@GxKn0ulm075gXAOoxJmrA7Je1zlJ0FhqkdIULqggzkGV0L4iZCoYhxjmYX9/iO84hOD7lp8QBzM5veHOonu0aDPC85C1YzChY6mn@A73i3FKrutSDiFDgqBJl1Mhvdsd9PMyISFJeow47fp2THAZAHKs5lLTAE4clTyAVPCzJVQAtVQmr112tJjPA1jhWeJZmDt@Es/u31jb91StIYrA3WadEPDHugaywxkOeLX5ki4OjJXJ0l5c02mqK6oLeEV3yNBjkw8NthxYM89obqobc3VjrAYOJx9VWCARjvuf4@KbZrVekz92yOixaqY4e8x8f0n/AQ):

```
int main()
{
    int valor;
    std::cin >> valor;

    auto [cien, cincuenta, veinte, diez, cinco, uno] = cambio<100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1>(valor);

    std::cout << "El cambio de " << valor << " es:\n"
        << cien         << " de cien\n"
        << cincuenta    << " de cincuenta\n"
        << veinte       << " de veinte\n"
        << diez         << " de diez\n"
        << cinco        << " de cinco\n"
        << uno          << " de uno\n";

    return 0;
}
```